# chrome.tabCapture to VLC

Tags: google-chrome-extension, video-streaming, vlc, video-capture

I would like to capture the tab of the Chrome browser and forward it as a stream to another computer which will play the stream via VLC. I am able to capture MediaStream of a tab of the Chrome browser using javascript and the chrome.tabCapture API, but I do not know how to forward this stream to VLC. Can you please give me some ideas? Thank you

Comment: You can probably use WebRTC to encode and send the stream. I see related info/solutions when googling.

Comment: Is WebRTC now part of HTML5 or the library must be installed separately? Thank you

Comment: It's built-in but this info is trivial to find, don't take my word for it.